# Find rows with list element that equals to something, in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have numpy array with lists:

```
[(26, 6, 2, 4, 'Bridge',  1.,  8, '2015-02-02')
 (23, 6, 1, 4, 'Bridge',  1.,  8, '2015-02-02')
 (12, 6, 2, 4, 'Back',  1.,  8, '2015-02-02')
 (23, 6, 3, 4, 'Back',  1.,  8, '2015-02-02')]
```

I need to filter numpy array by keeping only *lists* that have 5th element set to 'Back':

```
[(12, 6, 2, 4, 'Back',  1.,  8, '2015-02-02')
 (23, 6, 3, 4, 'Back',  1.,  8, '2015-02-02')]
```

Comment: What made you delete your [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46190442/find-rows-with-list-element-that-equals-to-something-in-numpy-array) and repeat it again here?

Comment: try to show your effort what have you done.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to specific programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets the given numpy array be referenced by `ar`

So,

```
>>> ar = np.array([[26, 6, 2, 4, 'Bridge',  1.,  8, '2015-02-02'],
... [23, 6, 1, 4, 'Bridge',  1.,  8, '2015-02-02'],
... [12, 6, 2, 4, 'Back',  1.,  8, '2015-02-02'],
... [23, 6, 3, 4, 'Back',  1.,  8, '2015-02-02']])
>>> check = np.array([a[4]=='Back' for a in ar])
>>> check
array([False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> ar[check]
array([['12', '6', '2', '4', 'Back', '1.0', '8', '2015-02-02'],
       ['23', '6', '3', '4', 'Back', '1.0', '8', '2015-02-02']],
       dtype='|S11')
>>>
```

Checkout boolean indexing of numpy arrays here : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html